# How to show/hide a magento block in javascript

Tags: magento2, blocks

I want to show/hide a block on button click event.
I am using javascript for this.
Here is my code, but its not working

```
$(".btn-block").click(function() {  
            if( $('.sidebar-main').css('display') == 'block' && $('.sidebar-additional').css('display') == 'block' ) {
            $(".sidebar-main").css('display', 'none');              
            $(".sidebar-additional").css('display', 'none');

                $layout = $this->getLayout();
                $layout->unsetElement('category.products.list');

            }
```

The code which i have use to hide the block works fine outside script, but giving error when placed inside script. How to overcome this?

Comment: @Ghulam.M i am writing this in phtml file

Comment: please share error from the console if any.